# How to validate mp3 format uploaded file in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hi guys how to i validate an upload files in mp 3 format? restrict all other format files except mp3 file.

heres my viewmodel codes

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
    [FileExtensions(ErrorMessage = "Must choose .mp3 file.", Extensions = "mp3,mp3")]
    public string SongAudioURL { get; set; }
```

Comment: Are you posting only the file URL or the file itself?

Answer (score 0):

You are using fileExtention with a string

```
 [FileExtensions(ErrorMessage = "Must choose .csv file.",Extensions = "csv,txt")]
  public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

Maybe a **regular expression** will be better